# Selecting objects overlapping a pixel in matlab

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I'm implementing some sort of flood fill algorithm in Matlab that, given a starting pixel in a binary image, will output a binary image containing only the pixels that can be directly connected to it.

Basically, let

```
foo =
     1     1     1
     1     0     0
     1     0     1
```

calling `flood_fill(foo,1,1)` would yield

```
     1     1     1
     1     0     0
     1     0     0
```

Now, I'm pretty new to Matlab.  I initially implemented `flood_fill` in a recursive style, but the pass-by-value behaviour of Matlab made working with large images very inefficient.  To fix this, I reimplemented `flood_fill` like this

```
function [outImage] = flood_fill(inImage,start_x,start_y)
    width = size(inImage,2);
    height = size(inImage,1);

    outImage = zeros(height,width);

    points = [];
    points = [points; [start_x start_y]];

    while size(points,1)>0
        point = points(1,:);
        points = points(2:end,:);
        y=point(2);
        x=point(1);

        outImage(y,x)=1;

        if (y>1 && (outImage(y-1,x)==0) && (inImage(y-1,x)==1))
            points = [points; [x y-1]];
        end
        if (y<height && (outImage(y+1,x)==0) && (inImage(y+1,x)==1))
            points = [points; [x y+1]];
        end
        if (x>1 && (outImage(y,x-1)==0) && (inImage(y,x-1)==1))
            points = [points; [x-1 y]];
        end
        if (x<width && (outImage(y,x+1)==0) && (inImage(y,x+1)==1))
            points = [points; [x+1 y]];
        end
    end
end
```

Now, this works on small matrices/images but takes forever on large images as well.  I suspect the reason why is the large amount of array resizes going on.  Normally (in C++ for example), I'd use an unordered linked list and use it as a stack (remove from and insert at the head) to avoid costly array resizes.

Is there an equivalent to such a data structure in Matlab?  If not, what's a Matlab idiom I could use?  Perhaps a built-in function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that you search for called `bwselect`:

```
foo=[1 1 1; 1 0 0; 1 0 1]
b=bwselect(foo,1, 1)
```

Note that you can define also fourth input `n` (like that: `bwselect(foo,1,1,n)`), that can have a value of 4 to specify 4-connected region, or 8 to specify 8-connected region.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  Although it doesn't answer the question itself, it solves my specific problem.

Comment: Thanks. For the question itself, I don't know for a linked-list-like structure in Matlab, but this function, for example, is the reason for high-level languages... :)

Comment: you're exactly right and I edited the question to be better aligned with your answer, you know, for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

Adiel answered your second question "Perhaps a built-in function?". As for the first part:

I'm not familiar with linked lists in MATLAB. However, you can speed up your function significantly by initializing the size of the points-matrix and don't change the size after that. Pre-initialization should **always** be done in MATLAB. If the function won't work with matrices of fixed size, I would always recommend you to try to rewrite the function.

For your specific case:

```
function [outImage] = flood_fill(inImage,start_x,start_y)
    width = size(inImage,2);
    height = size(inImage,1);

    outImage = zeros(height,width);

    points = zeros(nnz(inImage),2);  % I take it this is the maximum size
    points(1,:) = [start_x start_y];

    k = 1;                           % Increment row number in points
    while size(points,1)>0

        k = k + 1;
        y=points(k, 2);
        x=points(k, 1);
```

I understand it you have programming skills in general, so I believe you should be able to adapt the remaining code to the new format. (I don't have time to go through it and rewrite it). I'm quite sure it will run ***much*** faster!